# Virtual Scroll issue in Angular Universal

Tags: angular7, angular-universal, virtualscroll

I'm using angular 7 projects with universal integrated to it working around virtual scroll feature and am getting the following error(for server-side rendering)

> ReferenceError: window is not defined
>       at new VirtualScrollerComponent (/sample/universal/dist/server.js:150466:23)
>       at createClass (/sample/universal/dist/server.js:26257:20)
>       at createDirectiveInstance...

Any idea on how to handle this?